# Javascript to create custom formatted JSON from original JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects (`data`) such as:

```
data = [
{
    "stid": "ABC1",
    "name": "Some Name 1",
    "station_reports_percentage": 98,
    "station_reports_received": 200,
    "station_reports_possible": 210,
    "expected_freq": 15,
    "sensors": 6,
    "average_latency": 1.2,
    "last_report_time": 201907310000
},
{
    "stid": "ABC2",
    "name": "Some Name 2",
    "station_reports_percentage": 99,
    "station_reports_received": 205,
    "station_reports_possible": 210,
    "expected_freq": 15,
    "sensors": 5,
    "average_latency": 1.5,
    "last_report_time": 201907310000
},
{
    "stid": "ABC3",
    "name": "Some Name 3",
    "station_reports_percentage": 100,
    "station_reports_received": 210,
    "station_reports_possible": 210,
    "expected_freq": 15,
    "sensors": 6,
    "average_latency": 1.7,
    "last_report_time": 201907310000
}]
```

I would like to create a new array (`data_2`) using values from `data`, that is formatted for entry into a table display. The key strings are renamed, and the values for the `station_reports_` variables are combined into a single string. Such as:

```
data_2 = [
{
    "Station ID": "ABC1",
    "Name": "Some Name 1",
    "Station Reports": "98% (200 of 210)",
    "Expected Frequency": 15,
    "Sensors": 6,
    "Average Latency": 1.2,
    "Last Report Time": 201907310000
},
{
    "Station ID":"ABC2",
    "Name": "Some Name 2",
    "Station Reports": "99% (205 of 210)",
    "Expected Frequency": 15,
    "Sensors": 5,
    "Average Latency": 1.5,
    "Last Report Time": 201907310000
},
{
    "Station ID":"ABC3",
    "Name": "Some Name 3",
    "Station Reports": "100% (210 of 210),
    "Expected Frequency": 15,
    "Sensors": 6,
    "Average Latency": 1.7,
    "Last Report Time": 201907310000
}]
```

How can I create `data_2`, using JavaScript? An efficient solution is ideal, as this will be executed on the fly during a page load.

I am able to construct new strings from the original values, such as:

```
test = {"Station Reports": data[0]["station_reports_percentage"] + "% (" + data[0]["station_reports_received"] + " of " + data[0]["station_reports_possible"] + ")"}
```

However, I am struggling with proper `for` loop syntax using js.

Comment: Define efficient...

Comment: Just looking for a method that will be fast-loading on a web page. Once the original JSON is loaded, I need to create the second and then render into a table. Original could contain hundreds of entries.

Comment: Could be done using map and spread operator

Comment: Show us what you have tried. Stack Overflow isn't a free code writing service! There are various approaches you could take. Objective here is to help with your code, not write it all for you

Comment: @charlietfl I am new to javascript, and looking for examples using this re-formatting problem. I have made various attempts, but they are not worth posting. Overall I agree with your comment, and usually try to make more specific posts with defined problems. Thanks.

Comment: Ok...understand there is a leaning curve but showing any attempt is better than none. These sorts of *"modify my data for me"* questions occur numerous times a day and that is not what SO is about

Comment: Unrelated, but you don't have a JSON object. You have an array of objects. [There's no such thing as a JSON object.](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will help you get your expected result.

```js
let jsonData = [{
        "stid": "ABC1",
        "name": "Some Name 1",
        "station_reports_percentage": 98,
        "station_reports_received": 200,
        "station_reports_possible": 210,
        "expected_freq": 15,
        "sensors": 6,
        "average_latency": 1.2,
        "last_report_time": 201907310000
    },
    {
        "stid": "ABC2",
        "name": "Some Name 2",
        "station_reports_percentage": 99,
        "station_reports_received": 205,
        "station_reports_possible": 210,
        "expected_freq": 15,
        "sensors": 5,
        "average_latency": 1.5,
        "last_report_time": 201907310000
    },
    {
        "stid": "ABC3",
        "name": "Some Name 3",
        "station_reports_percentage": 100,
        "station_reports_received": 210,
        "station_reports_possible": 210,
        "expected_freq": 15,
        "sensors": 6,
        "average_latency": 1.7,
        "last_report_time": 201907310000
    }
];

let label = {
    "stid": "Station ID",
    "name": "Name",
    "expected_freq": "Expected Frequency",
    "sensors": "Sensors",
    "average_latency": "Average Latency",
    "last_report_time": "Last Report Time"
}
    
   
let newData = [];
for (let each of jsonData) {
    let newFormat = {};
    for(let name in each) {
        if (label[name]) {
            newFormat[label[name]] = each[name];
        }
    }
    newFormat["Station Reports"] = `${each["station_reports_percentage"]}% (${each["station_reports_received"]} of ${each["station_reports_possible"]})}`;
    newData.push(newFormat);
}

console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by "efficient". I recommend to keep it simple with an approach like the following:

```js
const data = [
{
    "stid": "ABC1",
    "station_reports_percentage": 98,
    "station_reports_received": 200,
    "station_reports_possible": 210,
}];

const data_2 = [];

data.forEach(o => {
    data_2.push({
        "Station ID": o.stid,
        "Station Reports": `${o.station_reports_percentage}% (${o.station_reports_received} of ${o.station_reports_possible})`,
    });
});

console.log(data_2);
```

---

However, if you need the data just once to render a table, I would just do all that on the fly..